# A group of checkboxes in reactive forms Angular

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, forms

I'm creating a contact form where I added some checkboxes. User can select multiple options and should select at least 1 box.
I need to pass all the selected checkboxes to api data But I don't know how can I set it in .html file.
component.html

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-12 mb-5">
    <div class="heading-layout3">
        <h3 class="mg-b-10">Please Choose Your Service:</h3>
    </div>
    <article class="feature1 col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="feature1" name="floor"/>
        <div>
            <span> Floor Maintenance </span>
        </div>
    </article>
    
    <article class="feature2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="feature2" name="deep"/>
        <div>
            <span> Deep Cleaning </span>
        </div>
    </article>
    
    <article class="feature3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="feature3" name="residential"/>
        <div>
            <span> Residential Cleaning </span>
        </div>
    </article>
    
    <article class="feature4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="feature4" name="commercial"/>
        <div>
            <span> Commercial Cleaning </span>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="feature5 col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="feature5" name="industrial"/>
        <div>
            <span> Industrial Cleaning </span>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="feature6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="feature6" name="sanitization"/>
        <div>
            <span> Sanitization Services </span>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
export class ContactComponent {
  contactForm!: FormGroup;

  get name() {
    return this.contactForm.controls['name'];
  }
  get email() {
    return this.contactForm.controls['email'];
  }
  get phone() {
    return this.contactForm.controls['phone'];
  }
  get services() {
    return this.contactForm.controls['services'];
  }
  get message() {
    return this.contactForm.controls['message'];
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _emailService: EmailService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      message: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      services: this.fb.group({
        floor: ['Floor Maintenance'],
        deep: ['Deep Cleaning'],
        residential: ['Residential Cleaning'],
        commercial: ['Commercial Cleaning'],
        industrial: ['Industrial Cleaning'],
        sanitization: ['Disinfectant and Sanitization']
      }, [Validators.required])
    })
  }

}
```

How can I pass the checkboxes data to the API?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) ?

Comment: This might help http://pinkpawmovement.com/2023/01/03/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-group-of-checkboxes-in-reactive-forms-angular/

Answer (score 0):

Hello to make the user choose at least 1 checkbox you can create a custom validator for your formgroup named service.

To create a custom validator in another file you can add :

```js
export function requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator(minRequired = 1): ValidatorFn {
  return function validate(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    let checked = 0;

    Object.keys(formGroup?.controls)?.forEach(key => {
      const control = formGroup?.get(key);

      if (Boolean(control?.value) === true) {
        checked++;
      }
    });

    if (checked < minRequired) {
      return {
        requireCheckboxesToBeChecked: true,
      };
    }

    return null;
  };
}
```

then instead of adding [Validors.required] replace it by `{ validators: requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator() }`

Your ngOninit should look like this :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  message: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  services: this.fb.group({
    floor: ['Floor Maintenance'],
    deep: ['Deep Cleaning'],
    residential: ['Residential Cleaning'],
    commercial: ['Commercial Cleaning'],
    industrial: ['Industrial Cleaning'],
    sanitization: ['Disinfectant and Sanitization']
  }, { validators: requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator() })
})
```

}

Comment: I've done the same but getting this error in export function:
``` Type '(formGroup: UntypedFormGroup) => { requireCheckboxesToBeChecked: boolean; } | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
  Types of parameters 'formGroup' and 'control' are incompatible.
    Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup<any>': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 2 more.ts(2322) ```

Comment: Try to change UntyedFormGroup to FormGroup

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: I've changed ValidatorFn to Validators also. The errors removed but form is submitted without selecting one option. The validator is not working.

Comment: You should use "fat arrow": `export function requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator(minRequired = 1){return (formGroup: FormGroup)=>{...yourcode..}}`. But the error will not disapeared. The error is about this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74947269/creating-angular-custom-validators-but-it-keep-throwing-an-error-of-abstractcon/74948329?noredirect=1#comment132354454_74948329)